# Collecting different attributes when crawling a website

Tags: python, web-crawler, schema.org

I've been creating spiders for different websites containing articles that output the raw text, text and URLs. I would like to get some more information, such as description, language, publishing date etc.

This is one example:

```
import scrapy
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
stop_words = set(stopwords.words("german"))


class AListSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'aList'
    r = requests.get("https://www.a-list.at/newssitemap.xml")
    xml = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)
    urls_wien = list(filter(lambda y: '/wien/' in y, map(lambda x: x.text, soup.find_all("loc"))))

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = self.urls_wien
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        try:
            yield {
              'raw_text': BeautifulSoup(response.css('.news-single-item').get(), "html.parser").find(class_="news-single-item").text,
              'text': ' '.join([i for i in word_tokenize(re.sub(pattern='[^a-zA-Z_\-ÖöÜüÄäßèé]',string=BeautifulSoup(response.css('.news-single-item').get(), "html.parser").find(class_="news-single-item").text, repl=' ')) if i not in stop_words and not re.match('[0-9]', i) and len(i) >1]),
              'url': response.url
          }
        except:
            pass
```

I have read that it is possible to collect more information using schema.org, could anyone please explain how this works?

Answer (score 2):

On my last project, I wanted to valide the items scraped while they are being collected, so I used [scrapy_jsonschema](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-jsonschema). Their page explain really well how to use it.

If you need help to build a json schema, this site is really helpful http://json-schema.org/learn/getting-started-step-by-step.html